# Windows XP checks disk twice and then gets a MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-xp, machine-check-exception

I am trying to safe my dads laptop. He tried to install a printer with a CD and since then the laptop wont boot. He tried to install drivers and utilities, the cd does not mention windows XP compability but windows 7/8/8.1/10... He is afraid that this caused the error.

The behavior is strange. The laptop boots and after the windows loading screen begins a disk check. The disk check cannot be skipped, although it says so on the screen.
The disk check cant find any errors and says that everything with the drive C: is alright.
Then a second disk check starts again for the C: drive and during this check the MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION occurs.

I tried starting windows in safe mode which leeds to a black screen with a blinking cursor.
I could start windows in safe mode with CLI and could run chkdsk /f but it also did not find any errors.
From then on I no longer could start it in safe mode with or wihtout CLI I always get a black screen with the blinking cursor.

Specs:

- Windows XP Home, SP2, FAT32 formatted
- AMD Turion 64
- Computer cannot connect to the internet
- The data on the harddrive is important and cant be deleted

Error message:
STOP: 0x0000009C (0x00000004, 0x80546270, 0xB2000000, 0x00070F0F)

Next I will try to reinstall Windows XP via USB using the repair feature.

How is it possible that multiple disk checks confirm that no problems exist with the hard drive but it still generate a MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION?

Comment: stop what you are doing ... recover the data first ... if you need help with the recovery, then ask a new question about it ... this question is about a different issue

Comment: chkdsk checks *file system errors* only.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else, **stop booting or using the HDD** in the PC. If there is damage to the file system, each time the disk is mounted and accessed, *more damage is done*, making it more difficult to recover files.

- On another PC, create a rescue USB device with disk imaging software such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61), [AOMEI Bootable Rescue Media](https://www.ubackup.com/bootable-rescue-media-creator.html), on one of the [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). **N.B.** If the XP machine is 32-bit, likely 32-bit software is needed, such as [Macrium Reflect FREE Edition 32 Bit](https://www.majorgeeksoft.com/macrium-reflect-free-edition-32-bit/). This should be created on a 32-bit machine, e.g., a Windows 8 32-bit instance in VirtualBox.
- Use the rescue media to *image the XP machines HDD*. This requires accessing BIOS and/or changing the boot order so the machine boots from USB rather than HDD.
- Mount the image and try to recover data, such as documents, photos, etc. to an external drive. You can try a tool such as [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) to recover partly erased files... but don't expect great success with commercial recovery tools.
- If that does not work, you can try operating on the actual HDD, in the knowledge you're likely to do further damage.
- Once all vital files have been saved, you can try reinstalling XP -- though I suggest going to Windows 8 (32-bit, likely), still well beyond end-of-life, or try a [32-bit Linux distro](https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/).

Answer (score 0):

There is not much software for XP anymore. Installing the particular Printer software not made for XP most likely did damage not simple to repair. Printers often install network or like software.

It will be increasingly easy to make this kind of mistake.

If you have the XP CD, you can try repairing XP.

Otherwise, you would have to see if you can reinstall XP (unlikely - no patches anymore).

Best to move to a supported operating system. The only supported Windows operating systems now are Windows 10 (2 more years) and Windows 11 (longer term).